# DIY paper clipboard that can hold stationery

Tags: stationery

I find that I do not have enough time to do my school homework. Self-improvement issues aside, one way is to minimise wastage of time, one aspect of it comes from transport which takes up 2h back and forth in a day.

I have been doing written assignments on this kind of clipboard currently(back view)

[image: this] 
which at the start only holds a pencil and eraser.  However after some time I realised I need more stationeries like highlighter of different colours, pens of different colours to annotate notes, or even an extension to put a phone so that I can do some handwritten notes while watching a webcast. Most of the time I would be standing due to peak hour traffic and lack of seats.

I have considered things like this but I don't really know if they can solve my problem, worth my time finding one due to lack of availability and worth my money(costs $37 [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/HUA-JIE-A4-PU-Leather-Portfolio-Multifunction-Document-Folder-with-Card-Slot-USB-Cable-Holder-iPhone/32828246799.html))

[image]

It seems like a substitute for a bag directly for the clipboard, but seems too bulky(equivalent to the size of 2 A4 sheets side by side) and only suitable only when there's a surface to rest the entire structure on, like a table. In the standing position I definitely need a left hand to support it, and a bigger file holder like this will only make the tasks harder.

Can anyone think of a cost effective solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a clipboard with storage. An example on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B007A1BU5G/ref=asc_df_B007A1BU5G55898697/?tag=googshopuk-21&creative=22122&creativeASIN=B007A1BU5G&linkCode=df0&hvadid=214522367922&hvpos=1o4&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8006184000601978975&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006568&hvtargid=pla-421020035269). If that's not feasible, you can use a pouch to hold different stationery items and carry along your clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

All the things you mentioned you want to do, you can use your phone to do them (since you have one).  It's just a matter of finding the suitable applications. Later you can print your work out if you need to.

Comment: I think if the work is something like doing math sums, it's a bit hard to do it on phone with a lack of support for math symbols. Written assignments are not limited to essays only.